# Testing if the Null Space of a Matrix Contains a Positive Vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be an $n\times m$ matrix, with $n<m$. Is there a way to test if the null space of $A$ contains a positive vector? By positive vector, I mean a vector with only non-negative entries and different from zero.

Comment: This is a well-known problem. Have you looked up before asking this question?

Comment: @KBS Yes I did. If you have any reference would you mind sharing it with me?

Comment: Not particularly, but I have seen papers related to that when I worked on a similar problem. When you mention "a test", what kind of test are you looking for? Would a numerical test be fine? Because, this is a simple linear programming problem.

Comment: When you say that you want to "test" this, do mean that you want to do this using pencil and paper or using a computer?

Comment: @BenGrossmann Using a computer.

Comment: Would a Python script work as an answer?

Comment: Yes! I would actually be more interested in a condition on $A$, $n$, and $m$ that could be written down. But I guess a Python script could be reversed into such a condition.

Comment: There are sufficient conditions for that in the literature. You may check whether those conditions are satisfied in your case. You have some obvious necessary conditions such that every row needs to contain both positive and negative entries.

Comment: @mzp I'm curious by the way, why are you looking for a positive vector in the nullspace?

Comment: @BenGrossmann It is supposed to help with this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4391486/287326. The vector needs to be positive because it is supposed to be the diagonal elements of a covariance matrix. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @KBS I've googled and searched the books that I have, and haven't found such sufficient conditions. Do you know a book or paper that covers that?

Comment: @mzp Check this out https://www.google.com/search?q=positive+solutions+to+linear+systems&rlz=1C1GCEA_enCH924CH924&oq=p

Comment: @KBS Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to find a matrix $M$ whose columns form a basis of the nullspace and solve the following linear programming problem:

\begin{align}
\min_x\quad & c^TMx \\
\text{such that }\quad & -Mx \leq -\vec 1\\
&x \in \Bbb R,
\end{align}
where $c$ can be any $m \times 1$ vector. We make use of the following "trick" here: if an element of the nullspace with positive elements exists, then it is of course possible to scale this element so that its entries are greater than or equal to $1$. So, it suffices to consider the constraint where all entries of the vector are strictly greater than $1$.

If you merely want to assess existence, then you can take $c$ to be a zero vector as I have below, but you might prefer to choose a different $c$ as a niceness heuristic. For example, taking $c$ to be a vector of $1$'s results in a solution with minimal  $1$-norm.

If the inequalities seems strange, that's because they have been arranged to accommodate the nature of the inputs to scipy's [linprog function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html).

Here's the Python script (modified for relevancy) that I used to deal with a very similar problem.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg as la
from scipy.optimize import linprog

M = la.null_space(A)
n,m = M.shape
c = np.zeros(m)
        
A_ub = -M
b_ub = -np.ones(n)

res = linprog(c,A_ub = A_ub, b_ub = b_ub, bounds = (None,None))
print(res)
```

The `print(res)` command gives you a summary of the result. The `True/False` after `success:` tells you whether a satisfactory vector $x$ exists. This condition is stored as `res.success`. The vector $x$ is stored as `res.x`, and the corresponding element of the nullspace is `M@res.x`.

---

Implementation of the simpler method, per the helpful comment:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg as la
from scipy.optimize import linprog

n,m = A.shape

b_eq = np.zeros(n)
c = np.zeros(m)

res = linprog(c,A_eq = A, b_eq = b_eq, bounds = (1,None))
print(res)
```

If the outcome is "success", then the feasible element of the nullspace is given by `res.x`.

Comment: Another (simpler) solution would simply be to find $x\in\mathbb{R}^m$ such that $Ax=0$ and $x\ge 1_{m}$. This is a very simple linear program that deals directly with the data of the problem.

Comment: @KBS... I don't know why I didn't think of that, thank you

Comment: It happens to the best of us!